# Can you omit the parenthesis from attributes with no params?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I noticed when I have `[Serializable]` instead of `[Serializable()]`, the code still compiles.

Is there a rule for this that you can omit the parentheses? Is it a good practice? It seems more readable to me unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no particular rule regarding best practices that I've seen anywehere on the subect.

Generally, I find that people who hand-type their attributes omit the empty parens, but code generation almost always explicitly includes them.

Answer (score 2):

You can miss off the `()` when the attribute constructor you want to use has no parameters, and you don't want to specify any optional parameters (property values).

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48zeb25s.aspx) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Yes omitting the attribute is legal from a language standpoint.  I don't know of any best practices surrounding it but in general I find developers omit the parens if they're not necessary.