# What is the difference between the Method attributes TestMethod and TestMethod()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for a C# project using Visual Studio Unit test fwk, and found that using **[TestMethod]** or **[TestMethod()**] -any of the attributes work fine. What is the difference between them?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference here.

Comment: you can read [Attributes tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) from MSDN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A attribute can have parameters. If you don't pass any parameters you can write
[TestMethod] or [TestMethod()].

Answer (score 2):

Attributes can be used with our without parens, although it seems like the general consensus is to use them.

[Can you omit the parenthesis from attributes with no params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448200/can-you-omit-the-parenthesis-from-attributes-with-no-params)

This consensus is most likely due to the fact that "regular" (i.e. non-attribute) methods must be called *with* parens.